# Port forwarding ip problem

Tags: raspicam, port-forwarding

I've set up raspberry pi 2 and installed MotionEyeOS with the help of this [guide](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-security-camera/)

My laptop is connected to wi-fi router and its ip address is static: 192.168.1.150. 
My router ip address is: 192.168.1.1.

My laptop ethernet adapter recieves IP: 192.168.137.1 and motionEyeOS camera interface has IP: 192.168.137.44. I have a stream setup at 8081 port. The question is how can i forward it now?

*Additional info*:
I tried to setup port forwarding with internal ip address as 192.168.137.44 and internal/external ports as 8081. But still i cant access my camera from internet by visiting [myip]:8081. I have a feeling i need to connect two internal networks first and then do a port forwarding.
Port forwarding from this diaposon 192.168.1.1-192.168.255.255 works fine.

Comment: You seem to have two networks, 192.168.1.X and 192.168.137.X. Please explain which devices are on which network, and how the two networks are connected.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev You are right, there is two networks. First network  192.168.1.X consists of router and laptop, second network 192.168.137.X consists of local ethernet adapter and raspberry. They are connected with ethernet cord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to expose your RPi via the router's port forwarding feature, the RPi should be connected directly to the router. Right now, there is your laptop between the two, and I expect it is not configured to forward packets from its WiFi interface (connected to the router) to its Ethernet interface (connected to the RPi). As a result, the connection between the router and the RPi cannot be established.

Comment: Thats because the bridge on the laptop works like a NAT blocking all traffic as per firewall rules